# mysql online dashboard from windows server

Tags: php, mysql, charts, windows-server-2012, dashboard

I need to create online dashboard using data from SQL database from windows server 2012. This dashboard should contain charts, and should be able to autorefresh data.

My biggest problem is how can I make an access to that SQL file (which is around 600mb) from windows server.

Making php based charts is not a big deal, also I have found plenty online services that are offering online charts, but my problem is how can I connect it, because, I can copy database, and make a chart from it, but it needs to be a "live" connection between win server and that website where I'm gonna place dashboard, becuase it's the only way to make autorefreshed chart (at least I think it is). I have also thought to autosync it with dropbox and then somehow make a connection with dropbox, but I think that's not possible. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please isolate an issue and show us something you have tried. Do you have problems with just connecting to SQL from PHP? What do you mean by "live" and "autorefresh"? What events do you need to cause refreshing?

Comment: I actually don't have any "Code" to show, because my main problem is not making a dashboard and making a SQL query for that dashboard. I will try to isolate and simplify my problem: I need to create online dashboard that will be available on some website. I don't have a problem with making dashboard, and choosing which data will be displayed, but i have a problem to connect it with database from Windows Server that will refresh that online dashboard every time when there is a change in a database (or 12h refresh). It's actually my first time doing this, so i don't have an idea where to start.

Comment: Your question is too broad, and thus unsuitable for this site, also, this has nothing to do with programming, so please attempt something, then if you find trouble, come and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I believe what you are looking for is some sort of architecture advice. So, let me try to help you.

First, you don't "refresh dashboard when the database is changed" (there's no way SQL will call some code on update), but rather create some methods at the back-end which do both: change the database and communicate with the front-end; and change your database only using them. Like:

```
function changeMyDB($options) {
    // do some actual changes and if that doesn't fail,
    // notify the user
}
```

Second, you need to understand which way to use to communicate with the user (how to "notify" them from the back-end when they don't do any request). Well, here you have 2 options. More straight-forward way is to use web-sockets (better to use with FastCGI than CGI, as far as I know) and the other (less proper I think) is to regularly send requests from the front-end to the back-end and refresh if there's pending updates which you will register with your `changeMyDB` function. Also I've heard about [pusher](https://pusher.com/) in this context couple of times, but I never really gave some time to realize what it actually is.